# How to plot xticks twice

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I have just began to write python codes lately and don't have much knowledge. So I have this code that plots a graph using matplotlib and I would like it to mark the xticks twice. But as you may already know the code only results in the second one.

Here is the part of my code where I try to mark the xticks where I want:

```
plt.xticks([min(AcceptableCapacityIndex),max(AcceptableCapacityIndex)],rotation=90)
plt.xticks(np.arange(int(Cycle[0]),int(Cycle[-1]),int(Cycle[-1])/20),rotation=90)
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(int(Cycle[0]),int(Cycle[-1]),int(Cycle[-1])/20),rotation=90)</code> to set the ticks and <code>plt.xlim(min(AcceptableCapacityIndex),max(AcceptableCapacityIndex))
```

to set the x-axis limits.